# How to read SSL/TLS Encrypted Alert code under Ephemeral RSA

Tags: ssl, wireshark

I am trying to debug SSL Encrypted Alerts on my web server.  I am not sure what the problem is and things appear to be working, but I am seeing many TLSv1 Encrypted Alerts in Wireshark that I feel should not be there.

The TLSv1 alert protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Alert_protocol) provides error codes indicating what is wrong, unfortunately this code is encrypted.

Wireshark allows the SSL to be decrypted by providing the private key (which I have) in the SSL preferences page.  However this does not work for me due to the session being setup with Ephemeral RSA (Sharkfest'09 http://sharkfest.wireshark.org/sharkfest.12/presentations/MB-1_SSL_Troubleshooting_with%20_Wireshark_Software.pdf page 59).

I want to know how I can read this alert code.  Any of the following will get me there:

a) Have Wireshark decrypt SSL using Ephemeral RSA

b) Avoid using Ephemeral RSA so Wireshark can decrypt

c) Force the SSL to use null encryption so I can just read the code to debug it

Answer (score 1):

> b) Avoid using Ephemeral RSA so Wireshark can decrypt

If you web server is Apache, try the following:

```
httpd.conf

SSLProtocol +all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite -kEECDH:-kEDH:+kRSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-EXP
```

> c) Force the SSL to use null encryption so I can just read the code to debug it

This might be a little trickier, but try moving `eNULL` to the front of the list. `eNULL` will probably be rejected by the client, but its worth a try. I suspect it will be rejected because the client won't allow the cipher (or `aNULL`, for that matter).

If the client does have `eNULL`, it still might not be used. The server usually honors the client's ciphers, so unless the client requests `eNull`, then you will have to find an override on the server configuration.

Comment: The server *always* 'honours the client's ciphers'. It has no choice. See RFC 2246, #7.4.1.2.

Comment: "The server always 'honours the client's ciphers'." Not in practice. I regularly dictate what cipher the client will use because clients are often misconfigured. I rarely take the number one preference of RC4/MD5. As a matter of fact, I cannot take RC4/MD5 since I disable them - both are broken. See OpenSSL's [SSL_OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_options.html).

Comment: You regularly dictate a choice among the client's enabled cipher suites. You can't do anything else. See the RFC.